# Configure Ajax request made by Kendo to support cross domain ajax request

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-autocomplete

The basic kendo auto complete example shows a setup where matched search results are fetched through an Ajax request. The ajax loading works fine if the requested resource is on the same domain, but I was wondering if there is support for configuring the underlying ajax requests to support CORS. Is there a way to pass in Ajax options like you normally would do if you were using `$.ajax({})` directly.

```
$("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
                        dataTextField: "ProductName",
                        filter: "contains",
                        minLength: 3,
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I basically want the same granular control over the request as in a regular JQuery Ajax request (example bellow):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'some url',
                data: {id:id},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "Get",
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                crossDomain: true

            })
```

Comment: If domain is different, you need to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on remote domain for client domain. This is about security

Comment: I know. The service is already configured to support that. I just need to make an ajax request that supports CORS

Comment: you can pass access token to your headers, and check that on server side. I am developing restful login system by usin nodejs. The communication simply done with access token generated username and password

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I can pass in the Jquery options to the kendo control that same way I do it for a regular Ajax request. I already have that working. I am just not seeing a way in the kendo control to specify the additional params. Kendo appears to use jquery behind the scenes with some custom abstractions

Comment: Added an answer with my solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to assign the read property to a method that wraps the ajax call like so:

```
$("#search").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        minLength: 1,
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read:
                    function(options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "someUrl",
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: { text: options.data.filter.filters[0].value },
                            type: "Get",
                            xhrFields: {
                                withCredentials: true
                            },
                            crossDomain: true,
                            success: function (result) {
                                 options.success(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This gives you the ability to replace the default ajax behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can set user on `beforeSend` method;

```
$("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        filter: "contains",
        minLength: 3,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                    type: 'POST',
                    beforeSend: function(req) {
                        req.setRequestHeader('Auth', your_token);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by setting withCredentials to true for the property  "xhrFields" of reader as below for the data source definition.

```
dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            xhrFields: {
                                withCredentials: true
                            },
                            url: serviceURL
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Make sure you have already set **SupportsCredentials = true** in the cors settings in the target server. 
Hope this helps