# Load Kendo Grid data Source from aspx page response.write

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

Hi I have a large data source that is to be loaded into kendo grid. So I am trying to load that datasource from an external page and give the url of the page thru transport:read property of kendo grid.

I have an aspx page that writes the json data thru response.write in page_load. But am unable to load the json data from aspx page into kendo grid. here is the code:

In page_load of aspx page:

```
 Dim final As String = serializer.Serialize(result)
 Response.Clear()
 Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 Response.Write(result)
```

In kendo grid page:

```
 var grid = $("#finalGrid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "http://example.com/test.aspx",
                                dataType: "json",
                            },
                            pageSize: 100
                        },
                    },
                    height: $(document).height() - 250,                       
                    groupable: true,.....
```

Am able to see the result of the page in page inspector section of google in Response tab. Can anyone please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with cross domain calls?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169823/configure-ajax-request-made-by-kendo-to-support-cross-domain-ajax-request

Comment: what are the other settings for the KendoGrid? (e.g. "columns" ) and what is coming back from the request?

Comment: Am returning a json object...and the columns are the properties of the returned json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to add Response.End() at the end, which deletes all the html of the page and returns only our JSON object